# Ionic Framework, Populate select (drowdownlist) from database

Tags: mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

Where is wrong with below code? I can get the JSON result directly through any browser, it just don't want to show up in the dropdown list

I am just trying to populate from mysql database to combobox in ionic framework.

**UPDATED SCRIPT**

Still get empty in the dropdown list. Anyone?

**addlist.html**

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-stable">
  <h1 class="title">Add Lists</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-view>
  <div class="list has-header padding">
    <label class="item item-input item-select">
      <div class="input-label">
        Category
      </div>
      <div ng-controller="AddListCategoryCtrl">
        <select ng-model="category" ng-options="x.category for x in data">
          <option ng-repeat="x in data" value="{{x.id}}">{{x.category}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</ion-view>
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('ionicApp.controllers', [])

.controller('AddListCategoryCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var xhr = $http({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/api/listCat.php'
    });
    xhr.success(function(data){
      $scope.data = data.data;
    });
});
```

**listCat.php**

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
getById();

function getById() {
    $sql = "SELECT id,category FROM tbl_category ORDER BY tbl_category.id";
    try {
        $db = getDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $category = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo '{"category": ' . json_encode($category) . '}';

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: have you tried `ng-repeat="x in data"` thats where the data from the web request looks to be

Comment: change to ng-repeat="x in data" but it populate {{x.category}} as its content

Comment: change the `x.category` to x.the field name you require.
also `console.log($scope.data)` to verify there is data

Comment: category is the field that i want and why when i add `console.log($scope.data);` it said that undefined?

Comment: set your `$scope.data` outside the `$http` call

so `$scope.data = {}`